# AURemoteIO::IOThread(18):EXE_BAD_ACCESS (Code1, address 0X20)

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, objective-c++

I am using following function to render the incoming audio.

```
static OSStatus audioUnitRenderCallback(void                       *inRefCon,
                                    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                    const AudioTimeStamp       *inTimeStamp,
                                    UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                                    UInt32                      inNumberOfFrames,
                                    AudioBufferList            *ioData{
     // App is crashing at this : 
AudioUnitIO *SELF = (__bridge AudioUnitIO *)inRefCon;

// MICROPHONE: take the sound received, render it into bytes and hand them to the delegate
AudioUnitRender(SELF->g_audioUnit,
                ioActionFlags,
                inTimeStamp,
                g_inputBus,
                inNumberOfFrames,
                ioData);

if (!SELF->recordingAudio) {
    memset(ioData->mBuffers[0].mData, 0, ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize);        
// Some other code goes here

}
```

I am getting the crash as mentioned in question. Am I missing something?